# How to auto numbering/increment number of every column in table using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using `foreach` and `implode` function with below code:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($dates as $date=>$hour)
{
?>
    <th><?php echo $i." ".implode("</th>\n\t\t<th>\n", $hour); ?></th>
<?php 
$i++;
}
```

The goal is to show incrementing column number but as i tested above code it was only show number 1.

My question is:
How to auto numbering/increment number of every column in table using PHP?

Comment: How is it possible? You are starting on $i = 0, so the first echo will be "0", after that is correct to put $i++ for the value increment. Can you show an example of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use implode.

Your $i gets incremented only once per set $hours, but you implode all hours in one go.

I don't know what is exactly inside your $dates array, and you didn't say what your desired output should be.

The way you approach it now will create a WHOLE bunch of table headers.

You know best what you want, but my guess is think you should not use implode, and your counter $i will work as intended.